# How to run this sql with query builder in yii

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to run `select * from tableName where create_time = update_time and ...` sql with query builder in yii, and not found an solution in page [Query Builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder).

Is there a way I don't know to do this, except for using `Yii::$app->db->createCommand(SQL)`?

Yii version 2.0.15.1

```sql
select * from tableName where create_time = update_time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ActiveRecord models for example:

```php
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%tableName}}';
    }
}
```

You can run your query like this

```php
    $query = MyModel::find()
        ->where(new \yii\db\Expression('create_time = update_time'));
    $models = $query->all();
```

If you are not using ActiveRecord you can use `yii\db\Query` like this:

```
    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->from('tableName')
        ->where(new \yii\db\Expression('create_time = update_time'));
    $rows = $query->all();
```

You want to use `\yii\db\Expression` in where condition to make sure it won't treat update_time as string value instead of column name.

You don't need to use `select()` method because if it's not used all columns of table are selected by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it work!, and i use `andWhere` to finish my SQL

Answer (score 1):

`Yii::$app->db->createCommand(SQL)` returns an instance of `yii\db\Command` class.

To execute the query you have to invoke `queryAll()` method on this object:

```
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(SQL)->queryAll();
```

NOTE: if you need to execute raw SQL and sort/paging data within a grid, consider the idea of using the class `yii\data\SqlDataProvider`.